# Highlighting current link whilst excluding some pages using CSS & jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the code below to highlight the current page link users are on, however i'm wondering if it's possible to have the jQuery look over my homepage link as I use an image click to take users back to the home page and the highlighting is applying to just underneath my link as well which I really don't want it doing. Thanks in advance (warning- not all too jQuery knowledgeable)
**jQuery**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('a').each(function () {
                if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
                    $(this).addClass('current');
                                     }
                  });
           });
  </script>
```

**CSS**

```
a.current 
{
    background:lightgray;
    border-radius:10px;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: have you looked at `not()` method or `:not` selector in jQuery docs?

Comment: Or just be more specific about the jQ links selector. So if they are in a menu `$('li > a').each(function ()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for the `each` loop at all as you can put that `href` variable into your selector:

```
$('a[href="' + window.location.href + '"]')
```

Once you've done that you can achieve what you're after using [jQuery's `not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/%3anot/):

```
$('a[href="' + window.location.href + '"]').not('#logo').addClass('current');
```

This assumes your logo image has the following markup:

```
<a id="logo" ...>
    <img ... />
</a>
```

Comment: Not too sure what my script should be looking like. Any chance you could lay it out for me?
I've had a bit of a play around with it but I can't get it to work.

Sorry for being a hassle!

Answer (score 0):

By "look over" I assume you mean "don't apply the class". You can do something like this:

```
$(function () {
        $('a').each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('href') !== 'index.html') {
                if ($(this).prop('href') === window.location.href) {
                    $(this).addClass('current');
                }
             } 
         });
 });
```

Assuming your home link has a relative href. (If it is a full/absolute path, you would have to modify that if condition if the site url changed).